# ControlsFX, unbind AutocompletionBinding from Textfield doesn't work using dispose()

Tags: java, javafx

I want a Textfield to show suggestions only when you write 3 or more characters inside the Textfield. I'm using the ControlsFX library to do this.

This is my code:

```
public class TestView{


private Textfield name;
private AutoCompletionBinding acb;


@FXML
    public void initialize() {

         String[] suggestions = {"ciao", "12345", "abcdefg"};

         name.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {
                if (newValue.length() >= 3) {
                       acb = TextFields.bindAutoCompletion(name, suggestions);
                } else {
                    if (acb != null) {
                        acb.dispose();
                        acb = null;
                    }
                }
            }

        });
}
}
```

What happens is that yes, the autocompletion starts only when i write 3 or more letters... but if i delete everything, the autocompletionbinding doesn't get disposed. It shows me suggestions even if i write 1 letter from that point on.

By researching online, i found that if you declare the autocompletionBinding like this, the dispose() method doesn't work:

```
AutoCompletionBinding<String> auto;
```

The right way to declare it is this one:

```
AutoCompletionBinding auto;
```

That's what i did. But still, it doesn't work. I want it to show suggestions only from 3 letters or more, and if i delete everything in the textworks, the suggestions shouldn't pop up until i input 3 letters again. Any suggestions?

Comment: *"By researching online, i found that if you declare the autocompletionBinding like this, the dispose() method doesn't work"*. That makes no sense at all. *"The right way to declare it is this one:"*. No: it is (almost) never correct to use raw types. Using raw types cannot change the functionality of a method call.

Comment: I know it doesn't make sense. But i found it was a sort of bug. Here's the link. https://superuser.com/questions/1417267/the-controlsfx-textfields-bindautocompletion-will-not-update-with-new-parameters

You can also find similar posts here on STO.

Comment: But that link is clearly nonsense. The user there is claiming that it's a bug to have multiple suggestion boxes; obviously this is not a bug in the library but is just caused by creating multiple autocompletion bindings for the same text field, just like you are doing in your code. I recommend *critically evaluating* information you find online, not just taking it at face value.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not exactly sure why disposing the autocompletion binding doesn't work, but your approach is just not the correct approach. Note that you're constantly creating new autocompletion bindings. Every time the user types anything, and the text is longer than three characters, a new autocompletion binding is created. (But note that even if this is fixed, it doesn't actually fix the issue.) The autocompletion binding works by, presumably, adding a listener to the text field's `textProperty`, and having two such listeners with non-orthogonal functionality is never a good idea.

The autocompletion will not be visible if the resulting suggestion list is empty, so simply return an empty list if the length of the text is less than three characters:

```
public void initialize() {

    String[] suggestions = {"ciao", "12345", "abcdefg"};

    TextFields.bindAutoCompletion(name, input -> {
        if (input.getUserText().length() < 3) return Collections.emptyList();
        return Stream.of(suggestions)
            .filter(s -> s.contains(input.getUserText()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I know this may sound like a not good idea, but i want to use this in a wider situation. I want to create 2 different bindings because, in reality, i want the suggestions to be retrieved using a JSON. So, if i write "ant", i want to use these 3 words in a JSON, and using the result list as the suggestions. Thus, creating new bindings every time i write 3 letters would update the suggestions with the new letters. It's tricky, but i think it might work, since i didn't really grasp how to use SuggestionProvider or similars in the current version of controlsfx.

Comment: @TrySoHard Just use the same concept. You should not be replacing the binding, just define a single binding with an implementation that provides the data you want given the user input.