Populating JavaFX ControlsFX Autocompletion Textfield resulting in duplicate content
I've been using the JavaFX ControlsFX TextFields.bindAutoCompletion() with asynchronous javafx tasks in order to populate autocompletion results from my neo4j database after a user enters two characters. The problem is that if the user clears out the text field and types new values to search, there are now two bindings, so two autocompletion popups show.

I need to be able to completely unbind the textfield from the old list and bind it's autocompletion to the new list. It seems the abstract method i'm using, dispose() doesn't do anything in the standard AutoCompletionBinding class?
    AutoCompletionBinding<Client> clientBinding;
    private void getClientAutoComplete(TextField clientNameTextField) {
        String input = clientNameTextField.getText().toUpperCase();
        if (input.length() < 2  && clientBinding != null) {
            clientBinding.dispose();
        } else if (input.length() == 2) {
            var queryTask = SimpleCypher.getClientAutoComplete(input);

            queryTask.setOnSucceeded(event -> {
                AutoCompletionBinding<Client> clientBinding = TextFields.bindAutoCompletion(clientNameTextField, queryTask.getValue());
                clientBinding.setOnAutoCompleted(e -> getClientData(e.getCompletion().getId()));
            });

            // Start the task asynchronously
            Thread queryThread = new Thread(queryTask);
            queryThread.setDaemon(true); // Set as daemon thread to allow application exit
            queryThread.start();
        }
    }

Here is the Javafx Task:
    public static Task<List<Client>> getClientAutoComplete(String input){
        Task<List<Client>> task = new Task<>() {
                @Override
                protected List<Client> call() throws Exception {
                    List<Client> resultClients = new ArrayList<>();
                    try (Session session = DatabaseConnection.getSession()) {
                        Result result = session.run(
                                """
                                MATCH (n:Client)
                                WHERE toUpper(n.name) CONTAINS $textFieldInput
                                RETURN n.id AS id
                                , n.name AS name
                                , n.phone AS num
                                """,
                                Values.parameters("textFieldInput", input));
                        while (result.hasNext()) {
                            Record record = result.next();
                            resultClients.add(
                                new Client(
                                    record.get("id").asInt(),
                                    record.get("name").asString(),
                                    record.get("num").isNull() ? null : record.get("num").asString()
                            ));
                        }
                    }
                    return resultClients;
                }
            };
        task.setOnFailed(event -> SimpleCypher.handleQueryError(event));
        return task;
    }

I feel like the solution is to create my own custom class that overrides some of the abstract methods of AutoCompletionBinding. But what is the best way for me to implement this based on what i need, which is the ability for the user to type a value that is queried against the database and then populates the text field, while also removing any previous bindings from previous input?
Here is what I have so far for my implementation, but I'm not sure what all I have to actually put in the implementation to get it to work?:
import java.util.Collection;

import org.controlsfx.control.textfield.AutoCompletionBinding;

import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.util.Callback;
import javafx.util.StringConverter;

public class Neo4jAutoCompletionBinding<T> extends AutoCompletionBinding<T> {

    protected Neo4jAutoCompletionBinding(Node completionTarget,
            Callback<ISuggestionRequest, Collection<T>> suggestionProvider, StringConverter<T> converter) {
        super(completionTarget, suggestionProvider, converter);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    protected void completeUserInput(T completion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

}


I tried to dispose previous autocompletion bindings everytime a new query was ran. But it didn't work, all bindings remained.
I tried binding to an ObservableList where the ObservableList was fed by the Javafx Task query results, but the binding never would update to show the newly added values. It would bind to blank list and stay that way despite the fact the ObservableList would add the new values from the database.

I'm expecting to be able to type in a few characters, hit the database asynchronously so it doesn't freeze the UI. And then show valid results, while also eliminating any previous binding so the bindings don't stack on top of each other and cause confusion when the user autocompletes and it autocompletes to the wrong value because the application focus was on another binding popup, as can be seen in this image:

Update: Adding a MCVE for others to troubleshoot and experiment with solutions:
Project Structure:

Code:
package com.autocomplete.example;

import org.controlsfx.control.textfield.AutoCompletionBinding;
import org.controlsfx.control.textfield.TextFields;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

//Run project using mvn javafx:run
//You can see the bindings coninutally stack on top of eachother by using the ESC key on the keyboard to move the front one out of focus
public class AutocompleteExample extends Application {

private static final ObservableList<String> names1 = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
        "Alice", "Adam", "Alfred", "Amon", "Alfredo", "Al", "Albert"
);

private static final ObservableList<String> names2 = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
        "Bob", "Conner", "Robin", "Fred", "Freddy", "Edward", "Fredward", "Mariam"
);

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    TextField textField = new TextField();
    
    textField.setOnKeyTyped(event -> {
        AutoCompletionBinding<String> nameBinding = null;
        String input = textField.getText().toUpperCase();
        if (input.length() == 2){
            if (input.startsWith("A")) {
                if (nameBinding != null) nameBinding.dispose();
                nameBinding = TextFields.bindAutoCompletion(textField, names1);
                nameBinding.setOnAutoCompleted(val -> System.out.println("You selected "+ val.getCompletion() +" from list 1."));
            } else {
                if (nameBinding != null) nameBinding.dispose();
                nameBinding = TextFields.bindAutoCompletion(textField, names2);
                nameBinding.setOnAutoCompleted(val -> System.out.println("You selected "+ val.getCompletion() +" from list 2."));
            }
        } else if (nameBinding != null && input.length() < 2) nameBinding.dispose();
    });

    VBox root = new VBox(10, textField);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 200);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Autocomplete Example");
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

}
POM:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.autocomplete.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>AutocompleteExample</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.release>21</maven.compiler.release>
        <javafx.version>21.0.4</javafx.version>
        <exec.mainClass>com.autocomplete.example.AutocompleteExample</exec.mainClass>
    </properties>
        <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-base</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.neo4j.driver/neo4j-java-driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j.driver</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>5.18.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.controlsfx/controlsfx -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.controlsfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>controlsfx</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>${maven.compiler.release}</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Default configuration for running -->
                        <!-- Usage: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>${exec.mainClass}</mainClass>
                            <options>
                                <option>--add-exports</option>
                                <option>javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event=org.controlsfx.controls</option>
                                <option>--add-modules=javafx.base</option>
                            </options>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

module-info file:
module com.autocomplete.example {
requires javafx.base;
requires javafx.fxml;
requires transitive javafx.controls;
requires transitive javafx.graphics;
requires org.controlsfx.controls;

opens com.autocomplete.example to javafx.fxml;
exports com.autocomplete.example;
}



I'm not familiar with this API of ControlsFX, but what happens if you keep a reference to the Task and cancel it when you want to send a new request?

Instead of using clientBinding.setOnAutoCompleted to create the auto complete dialog, can you try to replace the content of the existing dialog? In other words, try to overwrite the existing dialog instead of creating a new one.

Isn't the key to this making clientBinding have a greater scope?

@Slaw that doesn't work because the task returns results very quickly. There isn't sufficient time to cancel it before the binding to the initial query result is already returned and the Task value is consumed. The reason for the use of the Task rather than running the query synchronously is so that the UI doesn't become frozen the moment the user types in the second character, which triggers the query to run.

@dan1st your proposal is an interesting alternative I haven't thought of, but having to mess with the actual creation of the dialog feels like a workaround rather than a solution the root of the issue.

@SedJ601 I am simply proposing the solution of extending the AutoCompletion class because I feel like maybe it's a solution, but I need guidance on how to implement the abstract methods to effectively fix the issue. But I'm definitely open to alternative suggestions as well.

@GQ16, create an MCVE of your current issue, and I can run some tests.

@SedJ601 I added the MCVE to the question, please check it out and let me know if you find a solution!

See if @James_D answer here can help.

Thanks to @SedJ601 for the inspiration that led me to take a new approach which solved all my problems! In order to use results from a database, but also change the values that are bound to the textfield based on what is input. You must bind the textfield using a suggestion provider that is bound to a list. Then based on the On Key Typed, whenever the user input is at the length needed, you query the database and populate the query results in the list. This way, you only bind the textfield once, but constantly manipulate that list itself. I previously attempted to do this without using the suggestion provider using the method:
TextFields.bindAutoCompletion(TextField tf, Collection<E> c);

USING THE ABOVE METHOD will not work with manipulating the list.
You must use the suggestion provider method below in your initialize() method:
List<String> autoCompleteModels = new ArrayList<>();
@FXML private void initialize(){
    TextFields
        .bindAutoCompletion(modelQuickSearchTextField, input -> {
            if (input.getUserText().length() < 2) {
                return Collections.emptyList();
            }
            return autoCompleteModels.stream().filter(s -> s.toLowerCase().contains(input.getUserText().toLowerCase())).collect(Collectors.toList());
        })
        .setOnAutoCompleted( e -> {
            String model = e.getCompletion().split("\s\\|\s")[0];
            openExistingInventory(SimpleCypher.getModelData(model));
            modelQuickSearchTextField.clear();
        });
}

And then use this method "On Key Typed" (I have it as a seperate method since I'm using JavaFX FXML Scenebuilder, but you can also do textField.onKeyTyped())
//TextField On Key Typed
@FXML TextField modelQuickSearchTextField;
@FXML private void modelAutoComplete() {
    String input = modelQuickSearchTextField.getText().toUpperCase();
    if (input.length() == 2) {
        Task<List<String>> queryTask = new Task<>() {
            @Override
            protected List<String> call() throws Exception {
                List<String> resultModels = new ArrayList<>();
                try (Session session = DatabaseConnection.getSession()) {
                    Result result = session.run("""
                            MATCH (mo:InventoryModel)
                            WHERE mo.id CONTAINS $textFieldInput 
                            CALL{
                                WITH mo
                                OPTIONAL MATCH (mo)-[:EXISTS_AS]->(:InventoryItem)-[hcs:HAS_CURRENT_STATUS]->(:Status{id:'AVAILABLE'})
                                RETURN sum(hcs.qty) AS available
                            }
                            RETURN mo.id + ' | ' + toString(available)
                            """,
                            Values.parameters("textFieldInput", input));
                    while (result.hasNext()) {
                        Record record = result.next();
                        resultModels.add(record.get(0).asString());
                    }
                }
                return resultModels;
            }
        };

        queryTask.setOnSucceeded(event -> autoCompleteModels = queryTask.getValue());

        // Start the task asynchronously
        Thread queryThread = new Thread(queryTask);
        queryThread.setDaemon(true); // Set as daemon thread to allow application exit
        queryThread.start();
    }
}


Using @James_D answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/76615992/2423906
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import org.controlsfx.control.textfield.TextFields;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

//Run project using mvn javafx:run
//You can see the bindings coninutally stack on top of eachother by using the ESC key on the keyboard to move the front one out of focus
public class App extends Application {

    private static final ObservableList<String> names1 = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            "Alice", "Adam", "Alfred", "Amon", "Alfredo", "Al", "Albert"
    );

    private static final ObservableList<String> names2 = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            "Bob", "Conner", "Robin", "Fred", "Freddy", "Edward", "Fredward", "Mariam"
    );

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TextField textField = new TextField();
        TextFields.bindAutoCompletion(textField, input -> {
            if (input.getUserText().length() < 2) {
                return Collections.emptyList();
            }
            if (input.getUserText().toLowerCase().startsWith("a")) {
                return names1.stream().filter(s -> s.toLowerCase().contains(input.getUserText().toLowerCase())).collect(Collectors.toList());
            }
            return names2.stream().filter(s -> s.toLowerCase().contains(input.getUserText().toLowerCase())).collect(Collectors.toList());
        });

        VBox root = new VBox(10, textField);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 200);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Autocomplete Example");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}



SedJ601 thanks for highlighting the Callback Suggestion provider approach. But I also have the challenge of needing to do this using a database query to return the results. Can you highlight how you would do this when you have to retrieve the list of suggestions from a database?

@GQ16. Your comment turns your question into what I call a moving question and goes against Stackoverflow.  If your current question was answered, accept the answer. If you have a different or follow-up question, create a new question.

As it relates to your new comment. I think the answer depends on how big the database data is. If your DB data is not very big, just load the two queries into two different lists when the app starts. If the DB data is big. I don't see why you can't use the same idea with a task or something to retrieve the appropriate set of data.
